# Firebase throw 404 error when running in hybrid app

Tags: android, firebase, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Ionic 3 and Firebase js SDK. It's work well in browser and ios.
 But when i run app in android devices, it could not connect to firebase and threw 404 error.
I'm using firebase js SDK `4.10.1`. I tried to downgrade to `4.9.0` but no luck. Here is the error log frome chrome inspect tool: 

[image]
Any help would be appreciated. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Download your google-services.json from firebase console into your android app folder **/app/google-services.json**

Comment: Please check your SHA-1 certificate and your OAuth2 client in the google api console